# Using Action<Action> as a param, why isn't it possible here? What can I do solve this issue?

Tags: c#, delegates

Using Action as a param, why isn't it possible here? What can I do solve this issue?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)

        {

            int eventsNum = 1000;
            var evt = new CountdownEvent(eventsNum);

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            Action<Action> rawThreadTest = o =>
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                   {
                       o();
                   }).Start();
            };

            Action<Action> threadPoolTest = o =>
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    o();
                }).Start();
            };

    //Here I get ct error "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."  
            CallTestMethod(eventsNum, "raw thread", evt, sw, rawThreadTest);
            CallTestMethod(eventsNum, "thread pool", evt, sw, threadPoolTest);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    private static void CallTestMethod<T>(int eventsNum, string threadType, CountdownEvent evt, Stopwatch sw, Action<Action> proc)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        evt.Reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < eventsNum; i++)
        {
            proc(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                evt.Signal();
            });
        }

        evt.Wait();
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Total for a {0} : {1}", threadType, sw.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("Avg for a {0} : {1}", threadType, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / eventsNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the point of the `T` generic parameter on `CallTestMethod`? You dont seem to use/reference it anywhere.

Comment: Action<Action>  looks a bit odd. Shouldn't it be Action<parameterType>? But you aren't passing a single parameter.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I left a "rudiment" from previous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CallTestMethod has a generic parameter T which you are not supplying a type argument for when you call it.

However, it does not seem to be getting used anyway.

Comment: I accept your answer as an answer to my question but I marked Enigmativity's answer just because he post his answer a tiny bit earlier.

Comment: actually, mine was first. But OK :)

Comment: OMG, I should go home and sleep

Answer (score 2):

You're going to feel foolish, but your `CallTestMethod` method signature has an unnecessary generic parameter - `<T>`.

Take it out and you're good to go.